Can someone clarify what d(t) means?
In the paradox of a derivative, by 3b1b, he says at 1:49, "it's pretty common to name a function like this s(t). I would use $d$ for distance but that guy already has a full time job in calculus". What does he mean by this?
I know d$x$ means with repsect to $x$ but that's different from $d(x)$. I tried looking for answers by searching up "d(x) math" but I only got results about d$x$. I think he meant d$x$ but I just wanted to clairfy to make sure I'm not missing anything.

It's just a joke. Functions can be named anything - the name is a shorthand. If you name a function $d(t),$ the $d$ is not the same $d$ that you see in derivatives $dy/dx$ and $\int f(t),dt.$ It is just a function name.

You are asking not about the conventions a pre-calc textbook is using, but instead of someone who posted a video--presumably for viewer attention as much as to keep mathematical rigour. I take it they meant by the "that guy already has a full-time job" is that "$d$" is already used in $dx$ so using "$d$" for something else [such as another function $d$ that takes a single argument i.e., $d(x)$] would be adding confusion.

Thank you! an additional question, why s(t) instead of any other letter?

"$s$" for space? I am not positive but that would be my guess

I assume that this is, indeed, referring to conflict with notation like $\mathrm dx$. Even though $\mathrm dt$ and $d(t)$ are not the same, they are very similar, and there are further sources of conflict that are not as obvious:

If you have $d(t)$, you are at risk of writing $\frac{\mathrm dd}{\mathrm dt}$ when you take its derivative with respect to $t$. This is terrible notation to write and to pronounce.
Even the $\mathrm d$ we see in $\mathrm dt$ can end up with parentheses after it in a function-like manner. Some people do this when integrating by substitution: $$\int x \cos(x^2)\,\mathrm dx = \frac12 \int \cos(x^2) \,\mathrm d(x^2) = \frac12 \sin(x^2) + C.$$ The total differential is also sometimes written in this way, as in $$\mathrm d(x^2 + y^2) = 2x\,\mathrm dx + 2y\,\mathrm dy.$$

Plus, of course, many people are not careful to write the "d" in $\mathrm dx$ in a special font even when typesetting math, and it's a lost cause when writing it by hand.

Can you add an example of how $\frac{dd}{dt}$ can occur?

It's just another notation people sometimes use for $d'(t)$, just like $\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}$ is another notation people sometimes use for $y'(x)$.

For your indefinite integral example, wouldn't $u = x^2$ work? I would assume anyone at that level would use u-subsitution to simplify and to avoid confusion. (unless there's only one I guess)

What I wrote is just another way of writing the $u$-substitution with $u = x^2$, but some people have learned a different notation for it, and then they prefer it. (In some ways, it's less confusing, because it's more concise, but it's all a matter of what they're used to.)
